# jquery loop through JSON objects with different key name

Tags: jquery, json

I have this simple JSON object:

```
var data = [{"some":25},{"stuff":12}]
```

I want to loop through this object to access both the key and it's value in each pair. Currently I know how to loop when a fixed key like:

```
var data = [{"host":"foo","url":"bar"},{"host":"foos","url":"bars"}]

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
     alert(data[i].host);
});​
```

What about if the key is different and I need to access it as well as the value?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you wanna use jQuery only, but:

```
$.each(data, function (i, obj) {
    $.each(obj, function (key, val) {
      // do what you want
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an *array* of objects..so loop the array, then loop the keys of the object at that index:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var key in data[i]) {
        console.log(key + ":" + data[i][key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a jquery equivalent?

Comment: @MichaelSamuel -- You dont need jQuery...jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: i know that already :) I prefer the jquery syntax more though

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
var data = [{"host":"foo","url":"bar"},{"host":"foos","url":"bars"}]

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
     alert(data[i][key]);
});​
```